# joomla tinymce editor problem

Tags: joomla1.5

hi i am using joomla 1.5 for my site.
in this i  fetched the problem of tinymce editor when i clicked on any article the image button are not shown. when i clicked on edit html source button It showing only “{$lang_theme_code_title}” on the Title bar and all body is blank.

so plz help me to resolved out from this problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider trying the JCE editor instead of trying to debug Tinymce. I'm running JCE error free on over 40 sites. It has a superior image manager, link manager, and code view. It installs easily and is highly configurable. The only caveat is that you should disable the Joomla insert image, page break, and read more buttons as JCE has those built in.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/editors/88

Answer (score 1):

See this thread:
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=62545

Try adding www. to your domain. Most often this is the problem.

I searched joomla project for vars $lang_theme_code_title... and related... There are not. Looked at Tinymce editor, it has javascript driven language file...

Most likely problem is cause by JavaScript. Try using different browser ([firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html?t=48163.3) or [chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome)).

I read info on some other forums, some claim that temporarily disabling the antivirus solved the problem. I don't think that this will work, but you can try.

If none of this helps, you will need to give more information. Load firefox with firebug and see the NET tab for JavaScript files and Ajax Requests, most likely you'll find something interesting there (i think 500 Error)